# Which rails release is the best?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now Rails 3 has come out, which version is the stable rails edition? Rails 2.3.3 , or  Rails 2.3.4 ?

Comment: Closing as too localized - the question is out of date.

Answer (score 7):

Rails 2.3.3 and 2.3.4 are out-of-date on the 2.x branch. The most recent Rails 2 version is 2.3.9.

The most recent release of Rails 3.x is 3.0.3.

They're all considered stable.

Comment: thanks can rails3 working well with ree(ruby enterprise edition)?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 and 2 are both stable. Better use Rails 3 though

Answer (score 1):

In the Rubygems, every release is considered stable, so you'd best choose the latest one.
Only versions that end in something like "pre", "beta" or "rc" are unstable, but unless you specify explicitly that you want an unstable version, you will get a stable one.

Install latest stable version:

```
gem install rails
```

Install latest unstable version:

```
gem install rails --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently 2x rails version is being outdated. Rails 3x is on step .
Rails 3.0 has been stable .So I will recommend you to move towards rails 3x

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 is the best one and also stable .

Answer (score 0):

One of the key benefits of working with Rails is the vibrant community and regular iterative improvements that come with it. What that means is the pace of change will continue in all likelihood.  Rails 3 has a lot of improvements over Rails 2.  Since building on Rails 3.1 (I am currently building a project on rc5) I have to say there are a lot of very good features coming down the pipe (if you'll excuse the pun).

As a result, I'd say work with the newest version you feel comfortable with.  Rails 3 is stable and most of the gems you'll use, that are being maintained actively (and you probably don't want to be using gems that were someone's part-time project they've forgotten about, anyway), are updated for Rails 3 and new gems are skipping over Rails 2 in a lot of cases.

So, future proof yourself and minimize the changes you'll have to make later when you want to take advantage of things like the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline, or some of the other features slated for release.

Answer (score 0):

Edge rails i.e. rails 3.1.x is awesome with lot of improvements and bug fixes

Answer (score 0):

rails 4 is on way and hopefully will be released in apr/may 2011. release is likely to disable support for ruby 1.8.7....stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

i am very happy with 3.0.3. did not have the guts to upgrade to 3.1. At one point i will need to bite the ebullet